# ALV field in RIMARA20 program is missing after migration to S4HANA

Tags: abap, alv, s4hana

I have the following issue.

In the past, we have added some fields to transaction IH09.

However last year we migrated to HANA and a lot of programs were updated in the process including the program RIMARA20, which is the program behind IH09.

IH09 has worked fine with the added fields were seen.

Last week I was asked to add another field and I did it however although the field catalog has the new field, it is not shown in the output of IH09.

I have debugged the code countless times trying to figure out what is going on but I don't know what happens.
This program internally uses the function **REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY**.

We still have the former SAP environment and I tried to make exactly the same enhancement with this new field and I can see it as expected.

In other words; the same field, the same data element, and the same enhancement in both environments but in the HANA instance I cannot see it.

I'm truly frustrated because I see the new field in the field catalog but I can't make it visible in the report.

Any advice on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY has "remembered" the old catalog

Did you try [image]
to reset the layout / add the missing field?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want to tell you something interesting. First, I cannot see this 'Reset' button in IH09 however when I login with another language then the field appears. What I did was change the default layout and it worked. Thank you very much.